# Eclipse: organise throws?

Tags: java, eclipse

Let's say I have this method:

```
@Override
public A doSomething() throws FileNotFoundException { ... }
```

While implementing this method, it starts throwing `IOExceptions`, so I change `FileNotFoundException` into `IOException`. This violates the definition in my superclass, so in Eclipse I press control+1 and select the quick fix *Add exceptions to [superclass.doSomething]*

But now, the definition in my superclass looks like:

```
A doSomething() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException;
```

The first throw is now superfluous, because `FileNotFoundException extends IOException`.

**Question:**

Is there an easy way to have Eclipse 'organise throws', kind of like organising imports?

Comment: Maybe your real problem is that Sonar complains while it maybe shouldn't ? :)

Comment: Most probably, you are not implementing the contract expected by your library for `doSomething` method. That said you can always wrap your `IOException` in a `RuntimeException` and throw it.

Comment: @KDM Contract? Both classes containing `doSomething` are made by myself and I can change the contract as many times as I want.

Comment: @Manu oops :) I thought sonar was a library. Then why don't you change the signature to throw only `IOException`?

Comment: @KDM Did you even read the question? I'm just looking for a way to do this automatically in Eclipse. (Programmers are lazy.)